# How do you include a key listener in a separate java class

Tags: java

I have been working on a game of singleplayer pong for quite some time now, and I have managed to get the code to work by using the mouse to control the paddle. However, I would like to figure out how to include a key listener into this program so I can add a second paddle to make it a multiplayer game. Here is the code that I have now:

Primary class (also contains the ball class):

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Experiment extends JApplet {

    public static final int WIDTH = BallRoom.WIDTH;
    public static final int HEIGHT = BallRoom.HEIGHT;

    public PaintSurface canvas;

    public void init()
    {
        this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        canvas = new PaintSurface();
        this.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(3);
        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new AnimationThread(this), 0L, 20L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

    }
}



class AnimationThread implements Runnable
{
    JApplet c;
    public AnimationThread(JApplet c)
    {
        this.c = c;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        c.repaint();
    }
}

class PaintSurface extends JComponent implements KeyListener
{
    int paddle_x = 0;
    int paddle_y = 360;

    int score = 0;
    float english = 1.0f;
    Ball ball;
    Color[] color = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN,   Color.BLUE};

    int colorIndex;

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Pressed" + e.getKeyChar()); //This doesn't show up when I type a key
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    public PaintSurface()
    {
        addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter()
        {
            public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e)
            {
                if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x > 5)
                    english = 1.5f; 
                else if (e.getX() - 30 - paddle_x < 5)
                    english = -1.5f;
                else
                    english = 1.0f;
                paddle_x = e.getX() - 30;
            }
        });




        ball = new Ball(20);
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        Shape paddle = new Rectangle2D.Float(paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8);

        g2.setColor(color[colorIndex % 6]);

        if (ball.intersects(paddle_x, paddle_y, 60, 8) && ball.y_speed  > 0)
        {           
            ball.y_speed = -ball.y_speed * 1.1;
            ball.x_speed = ball.x_speed * 1.1;


            if (english != 1.0f)
            {
                colorIndex++;
            }
            score += Math.abs(ball.x_speed * 10);
        }

        if (ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() >= BallRoom.HEIGHT)
        {
            ball = new Ball(20);
            score -= 1000;
            colorIndex = 0;
        }
        ball.move();
        g2.fill(ball);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g2.fill(paddle);
        g2.drawString("Score: " + score, 250, 20);
    }
}

class Ball extends Ellipse2D.Float{
    public double x_speed, y_speed;
    private int d;
    private int width = BallRoom.WIDTH;
    private int height = BallRoom.HEIGHT;

    public Ball(int diameter)
    {
        super((int) (Math.random() * (BallRoom.WIDTH - 20) + 1), 0, diameter, diameter);
        this.d = diameter;
        this.x_speed = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
        this.y_speed = (int) (Math.random() * 5) + 1;
    }

    public void move()
    {       
        if (super.x < 0 || super.x > width - d)
            x_speed = -x_speed;
        if (super.y < 0 || super.y > height - d)
            y_speed = -y_speed;

        super.x += x_speed;
        super.y += y_speed;
    }
}
```

BallRoom class:

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class BallRoom extends JApplet{
public static final int WIDTH = 400;
public static final int HEIGHT = 400;
public void init()
{
    this.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    this.setVisible(true);
}
}

Run class:


public class RunExperiment {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Experiment exp = new Experiment();

}
}
```

When I run this code, the print statement does not execute, which leads me to believe that it never recognized that the key was clicked. I would appreciate whatever help anyone could give me.

Comment: Add the Listener using addKeyListener(this) in the constructor. Also ensure PaintSurface is focusable and has focus.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `addKeyListener` somewhere on the component that has the key listener.

Most likely, in your case, you want to say `addKeyListener(this)` in your `PaintSurface` constructor.

Comment: Can you please give me an example of the code I should write?

Comment: I added addKeyListener(this) into the PaintSurface constructor, but for some reason it still doesn't respond when I type a key.

Comment: @CodeWiz808 Make sure the component you added the listener to is in focus. The component must be in focus for the listener to work.

Comment: @Vince Emigh I'm sorry but I don't know what you mean by making sure it is in focus. Can you please tell me what to look for and how to make it that way?

Comment: I got it to work! Thanks everyone for all your help!

Comment: @CodeWiz808 When you click on a button, you will notice that it looks a little different from the other buttons. This button is now in focus. When you click on a component, you request focus to let the program know what YOU are currently focusing on. You must ensure that whatever you added the listener to is in focus when you want to listen to events. Every compoment has the capability of being focusable by setting `setFocusable` to true and callijg `requestFocus` after your compomemts have been displayed. If needed, I'll write an answer

Comment: Also, the first thing you should come across when you google "java keylistener" is a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) that is pretty detailed.